# Dictionary: Alphabetize the elements of a list and count its occurences

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

Hi so I've been trying to count the elements in the list that I have made, and when I do it

The result should be:

a      2
above  2
across 1
and etc..

here's what Ive got:

```
word = []
with open('Lateralus.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
       temporary_holder = line.split()
          for i in temporary_holder:
             word.append(i)

for i in range(0,len(word)): word[i] = word[i].lower()    

word.sort()

for count in word:
    if count in word:
       word[count] = word[count] + 1
else:
    word[count] = 1

for  (word,many)  in word.items(): 
    print('{:20}{:1}'.format(word,many))
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors so that the code provided here will actually run. Also, please provide a small sample input (contents of `Lateralus.txt`) and show the expected output. Also describe what your code does wrong; if you're getting an exception, include the full traceback.

Comment: (If you had trouble formatting your code for StackOverflow, try this: edit your question, paste the code in again, then immediately click and drag to select it all, then click the `{}` button in the interface or type Ctrl-K.)

Answer (score 0):

**@Kimberly**, as I understood from your code, you want to read a text file of alphabetic characters.
You want to also ignore the cases of alphabetic characters in file. Finally, you want to count the occurences of each unique letters in the text file.

I will suggest you to use **dictionary** for this. I have written a sample code for this task which 
satisfy the following 3 conditions (please comment if you want different result by providing inputs and expected outputs, I will update my code based on that):

> 1. Reads text file and creates a single line of text by removing any spaces in between.
> 2. It converts upper case letters to lower case letters.
> 3. Finally, it creates a dictionary containing unique letters with their frequencies.

#### » Lateralus.txt

```
abcdefghijK
ABCDEfgkjHI
IhDcabEfGKJ
mkmkmkmkmoo
pkdpkdpkdAB
A B C D F Q
ab abc ab c
```

#### » Code

```
import json

char_occurences = {}

with open('Lateralus.txt', 'r') as file:
    all_lines_combined = ''.join([line.replace(' ', '').strip().lower() for line in file.readlines()])

print all_lines_combined      # abcdefghijkabcdefgkjhiihdcabefgkjmkmkmkmkmoopkdpkdpkdababcdfqababcabc
print len(all_lines_combined) # 69 (7 lines of 11 characters, 8 spaces => 77-8 = 69)

while all_lines_combined:
    ch = all_lines_combined[0]

    char_occurences[ch] = all_lines_combined.count(ch)

    all_lines_combined = all_lines_combined.replace(ch, '') 

# Pretty printing char_occurences dictionary containing occurences of 
# alphabetic characters in a text file
print json.dumps(char_occurences, indent=4)

"""
    {
        "a": 8,
        "c": 6,
        "b": 8,
        "e": 3,
        "d": 7,
        "g": 3,
        "f": 4,
        "i": 3,
        "h": 3,
        "k": 10,
        "j": 3,
        "m": 5,
        "o": 2,
        "q": 1,
        "p": 3
    }
"""
```